# How to set different qmake configuration depending on debug / release?

Tags: qt

I need to specify different output and intermediate folders in my .pro file for debug and release builds. I created a following test .pro file:

```
release {
  message( "release" )
}
debug {
  message( "debug" )
}
```

But compiling this .pro file in Qt Creator with “debug” build leads to following output:

```
Project MESSAGE: release
Project MESSAGE: debug
```

It seems that both “debug” and “release” conditions are set to `True` O_O. Is it possible to somehow handle debug and release builds separately in qmake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMake CONFIG() function and 'active configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164490/qmake-config-function-and-active-configuration)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [the qmake manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qmake-function-reference.html#config-config):

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
  message( "release" )
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  message( "debug" )
}
```

I don't really get the explanation, though. It seems that both of the options are really selected, and only one of them is "active". But qmake is famous for counter-intuitive things.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18164490/26449) question and its answer for explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
message("debug")
} else {
message("release")
}
```

the `qmake` will display "debug" if you are building your project in a `debug` or `debug|release` mode, otherwise (i.e.: if you are building it in a `release` mode) a "release" message will be shown.